# Redirecting traffic for inside network, and allow this from only IP address

Tags: iptables, firewalld

I have problem with iptables. In IP tables I make redirect traffic from port 4440 to inside IP Adresses 10.0.10.102:4440

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4440 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.10.102:4440
```

This redirect work correctly, and in this moment access for this is open for all.

Now, I want give access this traffic only from my IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a source address to filter for.

`-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -s $source-ip --dport 4440 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.10.102:4440`

You can also filter on forwarding, and you're honestly supposed to do it that way. Let the prerouting take care of NAT and you filter on FORWARD. Check out these links for a little more information!

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/iptables-source-address-state-and-dnat-775291/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/579231/whats-the-difference-between-prerouting-and-forward-in-iptables